# Is my thought process for calculating $\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)^-}\tan(x)^{\cos(x)}$ correct?

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

So I was doing calculus for fun, and decided to do some limits just for practice. After a while, I decided to give myself an $\infty^0$ indeterminate form:$$\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)^-}\tan(x)^{\cos(x)}$$which I felt like I might be able to calculate. Here is my attempt at doing so:

First, I know I can rewrite this as$$\exp\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)^-}\cos(x)\ln(\tan x)$$and then$$\exp\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)⁻}\dfrac{\ln\tan x}{\sec x}$$and now since this leaves us with an $\dfrac\infty\infty$ indeterminate form, we can apply L'Hôpital's rule to the limit to get:$$\exp\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)^-}\dfrac{\sec(x)}{\tan^2(x)}$$which since that gets us a $0\cdot\infty$ form, we take the derivative of the numerator and denominator again to get$$\require{cancel}\dfrac{\cancel{\sec x}^1\cancel{\tan x}}{2\cancel{\tan x}\cancel{\sec^2 x}^{\sec x}}=\dfrac12\cos x$$and then taking the exp of our limit gets $1$? For some reason, I felt like this couldn't be correct, until I plugged into [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Limit%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29tanx%5C%2841%29%2Ccosx%5D%2Cx-%3EDivide%5Bpi%2C2%5D%2CDirection-%3E1%5D) and was able to verify that it was correct. But for some reason, I feel like I must have messed up one of my steps, like when I first applied L'Hôpital's rule. There, I pretty much assumed that$$\dfrac d{dx}\ln(y(x))=\dfrac{y'}y\implies\dfrac d{dx}\ln\tan x=\sec x$$although I don't remember if this is true for all functions $y(x)$ or if there are certain restrictions, so my question is:

#### Is my thought process for calculating $\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)^-}\tan(x)^{\cos(x)}$ correct, or did I mess up any of my steps?

Comment: there seems to be some error in the notation, why is there a sec in the exponent after the second differentiation? (The point where some terms cancel out?)

Comment: @watertrainer The notations is not an exponent. The idea is probably that you cross out an expression and write what remains. Not a good notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac d{dx}\ln(y(x))=\dfrac{y'}y$$ holds as long as $\ln(y(x))$ is defined, i.e. as long as $y(x)$ is strictly positive. As one can see, as $x\rightarrow\dfrac{\pi}{2}^-$, $y(x) = \tan x$ is always positive, and thus the relation holds true in your case.

The rest of your solution seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved in an elementary way basing on $\lim_{y\to 0^+}y^y=1.$ We have
$$(\tan x)^{\cos x}={(\sin x)^{\cos x}\over (\cos x)^{\cos x}}$$ The numerator tends to $1.$ The denominator tends to $1$ as by substitution $y=\cos x$ we are reduced the limit mentioned above.

**Remark** The limit $ \lim_{y\to 0^+}y^y=1$ can be justified basing on $\lim_nn^{1/n}= 1.$